# Java Generics putting on Map<String, ? extends List<String>>

Tags: java, generics, list, collections, dictionary

Is there a way to make the following implementation in a type safe manner?

```
public void myMethod( Map<String, ? extends List<String>> map )
{
   map.put("foo", Collections.singletonList("bar");
}
```

The above implementation doesn't work. It requires a `Map<String, ? super List<String>>` to compile the method `map.put()` correctly. But myMethod won't accept any subtype of List this way. So, I have to use `Map<String, ? extends List<String>>` instead. How can I solve this problem in a type safe manner?

Answer (score 20):

```
public void myMethod( Map<String, List<String>> map ) {
    map.put("foo", Collections.singletonList("bar") );
}
```

You can't put a `List` (the return type of `Collections.singletonList()` into a `Map` of `? extends List` since the actual type could be any implementation of `List`. For example, it is *not* safe to put a generic `List` into a `Map<String,LinkedList>` since the `List` might not be a `LinkedList`. However, we can easily put a `LinkedList` into a `Map` of `<String,List>`.

I think you were over thinking your generics. You do not have to use `? extends` for a non-generic class. For example, `List<Object>` will hold any `Object`, the `? extends` is not needed to add an object. A `List<List<Foo>>` will only take `List<Foo>` objects and not `List<FooSubclass>` objects [Generic classes don't inherit based on their parameters]. This is where `? extends` comes into play. To add both `List<Foo>` and `List<FooSubclass>` to a `List`, the type must be `List<List<? extends Foo>>`.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation (now that your generics are visible :P).

Comment: Oops. I keep thinking that since SOF filters text anyway that it fixes the angled bracket stuff. Oh well...

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't `Map<String, List<String>` work? Is there some particular reason you have to have a wildcard there at all?

Answer (score 4):

There is a very simple principle when using Collections and Generics together. It is called "The Get and The Put Principle":

Use an "extends" wildcard when you only GET values out of a collection, use "super" wildcard when you only PUT values into a collection and don't use any wildcard when you want both get and put.

So, as you can see, the initial example is invalid, according to this principle.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if someone passed you a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`. The value you're putting in is the result of Collections.singletonList which is *not* an `ArrayList`.

You cannot accept any subtype of List in the Map and then expect to be able to add your own, possibly incompatible, subtype.