# How to use Java generic correctly where ? extends Set<Integer>

Tags: java, generics

First, I tried to use

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();
```

, but it did not compile because no casting is available.

Then I tried

```
Map<Integer, ? extends Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();
```

. It seemed to work, but when I tried to call

```
map.put(i, new HashSet<Integer>());
```

, it turned out to be a failure due to uncompatibility.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871521/java-generics-putting-on-mapstring-extends-liststring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871521/java-generics-putting-on-mapstring-extends-liststring)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
map.put(1, new HashSet<Integer>());
```

When you retrieve the value from the map, then it will be of type `Set<Integer>`, but that shouldn't make any difference as per your expectation. But if you want to retrieve only `HashSet<Integer>` then your map definition should be

```
Map<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: just to clarify - that's java 7 only.